# How to stop the toggle/show item in react-bootstrap Dropdown?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

code:-

```
<td style={{ color: "white", width: "250px" }}>
                                        <DropdownButton id="SelectFocus" title={playdata.ChannelName} tabIndex={-1}
                                            onToggle={ontoggle}
                                            menuVariant='dark'                                           
                                        >
                                            {Channelname.map((val, id) => {
                                                {
                                                    return (
                                                        <Fragment key={id}>
                                                            {removeRedundant([...val, playdata.ChannelName]).map((val1) => {
                                                                return (
                                                                    <Dropdown.Item
                                                                        onClick={(e) => { setPlayer(val1, playdata.idx, StoreIdx) }}
                                                                        key={val1}>{val1}</Dropdown.Item>
                                                                )
                                                            })}
                                                        </Fragment>
                                                    )
                                                }
                                            })
                                            }

                                        </DropdownButton>
                                    </td>
```

I am using react bootstrap for dropdown when I press down key button its automatically open the items/options how can I stop that?
i don't want item appear when I press the down key so how can I stop that in react js?

Please help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use DropdownButton component, there is an additional div around the button. Use more low level Dropdown components to set tabIndex on button directly:

```
<Dropdown>
    <Dropdown.Toggle tabIndex={-1}>Test</Dropdown.Toggle>
    <Dropdown.Menu>
      <Dropdown.Item>Test 1</Dropdown.Item>
      <Dropdown.Item>Test 2</Dropdown.Item>
      <Dropdown.Item>Test 3</Dropdown.Item>
    </Dropdown.Menu>
  </Dropdown>
```

But keep in mind once you have focused the dropdown with click, you will get the same behaviour when pressing arrow down.

To prevent dropdown from toggling I believe you can use the onKeyDown event, but I wasn't able to get it work so far:

```
const handleKeyDown = (event) => {
if (event.key === "ArrowDown") {
  event.preventDefault();
}
};
```